# How to get item from list by giving index number?

Tags: c++, list

I'm making program that will read text file
and place each word in list
named content
and I have problem
I don't know how to get
words from that list
in python it is
'content[index_number]'.
thanks in advance!

```
//importing//
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <list>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;
using std::ifstream;

int main() 
{
std::string str = "";
std::list <string> content;

std::cout << "enter file name to read" << endl;
std::cin >> file;

//reading data//
ifstream indata;
std::string str;
indata.open(file);
indata >> str;
while (!indata.eof()) { indata >> str; content.push_back(str);}
indata.close();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `auto it = content.begin(); it = std::next(it, index_number); std::cout << *it << "\n";`  Depending on how much indexing you need to do, a `std::vector<string> content;` might be a more suitable data structure.

Comment: Don't use `!indata.eof()`, just use `indata`.  There are conditions other than EOF that make it impossible to continue reading a file, and the implicit cast to `bool` catches all of them.

Comment: Python lists and C++ lists are very different. A Python list is arguably closer to a vector or deque in C++, while a C++ list is a so-called doubly-linked list, which--unlike a vector or Python list--does *not* support direct access to its individual elements through an index.

Comment: TYSM all of you !

Comment: Extension to Mark Ransom's comment about not using eof, you need to either move the `indata >> str;` in the loop body to after `content.push_back(str);` or change the `while` exit condition to `while (indata >> str)`  and remove the stand-alone `indata >> str`s. Currently the `indata >> str;` outside the loop is tested by the `while` loop and then `str` is overwritten by the `indata >> str;` inside the loop and will be lost. Plus the `str` read in the loop is immediately used, before the validity of the read is tested in the next loop iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python lists are arrays and allow random access. So do the same in C++ and put your words in `std::vector<std::string> content` and you have `content[i]` just like in python, although `content.at(i)` is safer so use that.